Skype Bot Not Responding to Group Messages
I’m currently developing a bot using the BotBuilder SDK (v4) and the Microsoft Bot Framework, and I’ve successfully registered it on Azure with Skype as one of the channels. The bot works well for 1:1 conversations and mentions within group chats. However, I’d like to explore the possibility of having the bot listen to all messages or events sent in a group it has joined, not just by mentions.
I came across this GitHub issue (https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/355) that mentions this feature can be enabled via configuration, but it seems that the only way to get it enabled is by submitting a support ticket. Since I’m on the free tier, I’m unable to create a support ticket, and I don’t want to upgrade to a paid support plan ($29/month) just to confirm if this feature is possible.
Before I consider other options, I’m wondering:

Is contacting Azure through a support ticket the only way to enable this feature?
Can this be achieved purely through code?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
